# How to avoid text from not showing at the bottom of the a ClipRRect that is rounded at the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a  ClipRRect that is rounded at the bottom and it contains text in it. The problem I am facing now is that I can not add some padding at the bottom of the ClipRRect and my text in the widget gets cut out and when I wrap the ClipRRect with padding widget or add a sized box after the text I get overflow error.

```
ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
      ),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Text(
          description,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I am expecting my text not to be cut out at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to the text.

```
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:8.0),child: Text(""),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding from Container.

```dart
child: Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  color: Colors.grey,
  child: Text(
```

Actually you can minimize the snippet like

```dart
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // if needed
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.grey,
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
    ),
  ),
  child: Text(
    description,
    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
  ),
),
```